# How to read only text file from sdcard in android?

Tags: android

HI...

I am New To Android, My requirement is to display Total SDcard files in Listview , in that i want to read only TextFiles.
 Can anyone HelpMe....
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [FilenameFilter](http://d.android.com/reference/java/io/FilenameFilter.html).

Something like this:

```
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {          
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return (filename.endsWith(".txt"));
    }
};
```

And:

```
String[] list = dir.list(filter);
```

There you go! :)